# How to select rows in complicated condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
A B  C
1 a A0
1 b A1
1 c B0 
2 d B1
2 e B2
2 f B3
3 g A2
3 h A3
```

First, I would like to group by `df.A` the first one (`df_sub` is below)

```
df_sub1

A B C
1 a A0
1 b A1
1 c B0

df_sub2

A B C
2 d B1
2 e B2
2 f B3

df_sub3

A B C
3 g A2
3 h A3
```

Second,If each `df_sub.C` contains the string begins with `"A"` each `df_sub` is entirely concatenated.

In this case, `df_sub1` and `df_sub3` whose column C has string begin with `"A"` so that `df_sub1` and `df_sub2` is concatenated

so I would like to get the result below

```
A B C
1 a A0
1 b A1
1 c B0
3 g A2
3 h A3
```

In my opinion, I must split the `df` by column A, and after some process concatenate.

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with another `DataFrame` filtered by mask created by [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df1 = df[df.A == 1]
print (df1)
   A  B   C
0  1  a  A0
1  1  b  A1
2  1  c  B0

df2 = df[df.A != 1]
print (df2)
   A  B   C
3  2  d  B1
4  2  e  B2
5  2  f  B3
6  3  g  A2
7  3  h  A3

print (pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.C.str.startswith('A')]]))
   A  B   C
0  1  a  A0
1  1  b  A1
2  1  c  B0
6  3  g  A2
7  3  h  A3
```

More general solution is select first value of `A` for compare:

```
df1 = df[df.A == df.A.iat[0]]
print (df1)
   A  B   C
0  1  a  A0
1  1  b  A1
2  1  c  B0

df2 = df[df.A != df.A.iat[0]]
print (df2)
   A  B   C
3  2  d  B1
4  2  e  B2
5  2  f  B3
6  3  g  A2
7  3  h  A3

print (pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.C.str.startswith('A')]]))
   A  B   C
0  1  a  A0
1  1  b  A1
2  1  c  B0
6  3  g  A2
7  3  h  A3
```

---

If need all groups `groupby` by column `A` is possible use [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) with condition find at least one value in `C` which starts with `A`:

```
print (df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x.C.str.startswith('A').any())) 
   A  B   C
0  1  a  A0
1  1  b  A1
2  1  c  B0
6  3  g  A2
7  3  h  A3
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right and you want to exclude the rows where `'A'` is 2:

```
df[df['A'] != 2]
```

You can also include a condition for `startswith`:

```
df[df['C'].str.startswith('A')]
```

---

That might not be enough, maybe your dataset was somewhat biased (because both simple approaches worked :-))

You could also iterate over groups and remove groups that don't satisfy your condition:

```
for idx, subdf in df.groupby(['A']):
    # print(subdf)  # this prints your groups

    # remove groups where not any (use all if you want all) C column starts with A
    if not subdf.C.str.startswith('A').any():
        df = df[df['A'] != idx]

print(df)
```